# Can we divided the irrationals into a countable disjoint union of subsets, none of which has a rational limit point?

Tags: real-analysis

If we partite $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ as  $\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ if $i\ne j$, can it hold that $A_i$ **has no rational limit point**?

Actually, we have irrational perfect sets, but they don't seem to be able to contain much of $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. Or if we can express the irrationals as a disjoint union of such sets, then we are done. But this too seems hopeless.

---

Furthurmore, does it hold that $\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\bar{A_i}=\mathbb{R}$?

Actually, this is a **strengthening** of the first problem. The first one seeks to prove that whatever partition we make, the outcome cannot be too coarse. The second one further discusses whether it is still dense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot hold.

Your problem asks for a family $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $A_i'\cap\mathbb Q=\emptyset$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$, but this means $\overline{A_i}\cap\mathbb Q=\emptyset$, as $\overline{A_i}=A_i\cup A_i'$ and $A_i\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, but this is equivalent to $\mathbb Q\subseteq \overline{A_i}^c=int(A_i^c)$ for all $i$. Thus your problem, ignoring the disjointedness part, is equivalent to finding a family $\{A_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of sets of reals such that $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i=\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q\subseteq int(A_i)$ for all $i$, but this cannot happen because of [Baire's First Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem):

Let $\mathbb Q=\{q_i:i\in\mathbb N\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. As $\mathbb Q\subseteq int(A_i)$ for each $i$, each $int(A_i)$ is open dense in $\mathbb R$, then clearly each $int(A_i)\setminus\{q_i\}$ is open dense in $\mathbb R$; as $int(A_i)$ either contains an open interval that contains $q_i$; in such case $q_i\in \overline {int(A_i)\setminus\{q_i\}}$, or $q_i\notin int(A_i)$. Therefore $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}(int(A_i)\setminus\{q_i\})$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, by [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). However $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} int(A_i)\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i=\mathbb Q$, which implies $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}(int(A_i)\setminus\{q_i\})=\emptyset$. Contradiction.

Now, if you ask for $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} \overline{A_i}=\mathbb R$, it's even easier, as this means $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} int(A_i^c)=\emptyset,$ however, $\mathbb Q\subseteq int(A_i^c)$ for each $i$, in consequence each $int(A_i^c)$ is open dense, so you obtain a contradiction using [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Comment: It's actually $\overline{int(A)}\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset$. It implies $\overline{A}\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset$ in this case though.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward what do you mean?

Comment: I mean we should exclude the isolated point (i.e. consider the derived set, not the closure).

Comment: @AnonymousCoward But there is no need to, as $\overline {A_i}=A_i\cup A_i'$ and $A_i\subseteq \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, so $A_i'\cap\mathbb Q=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $\overline{A_i}\cap\mathbb Q=\emptyset$.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward, have you checked my edit?

Comment: I think you took it wrong. The second problem is discussed without assuming the sets having no rational limit point. But $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathrm{int}(A_i^c)$ in your argument is a consequence of that.

Comment: It is unbelievable that the assertion is always false. For the trivial partition $A_1=\mathbb{Q}$ and empty otherwise, clearly $\overline{A_1}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What are the $A_i$'s in the second question?, you weren't clear enough...

Comment: I have now modified the problem to be clear. $A_i$ is always a partition of the irrationals. In the first question I ask whether at least one of them they have at least one rational limit point. In the second one I ask whether they always have every point as a limit point (of at least one of them), which is a considerable strengthening of the first one.